# VBA - use color already select in Excel to fill cell interior

Tags: colors, excel, vba

I know how to set the interior color of a cell to a certain color, but is there a way to do it so that it (i.e., the cell color) defaults to the color already selected in the color window of the ribbon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting to this very late but since it popped up in a google search for something else, I thought I'd mention the selected answer is incorrect when it says you cannot do what the submitter wanted.  You can activate the control directly with...

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"
```

...and it will apply the currently selected color to the selected range.

I'm actually looking around to see if there is a way to select another color in the control's gallery via VBA so I can make the default "no fill" rather than yellow when first opening a workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* get the currently selected , but I wish it was easier..

This is an example of capturing it based on the code supplied by @justpassingthrough.

Instead of Debug.print - you could save the value into a global variable perhaps?

```
      Sub HiddenSheetGetColor()


      Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' :: STOP SCREEN FLASHES

      Dim HiddenSheetName  As String   ':: VARIABLE TO SHEET NAME

      HiddenSheetName = Format(Now(), "__YYYYMMDD_HH_MM_SS_.00")  ' TIMESTAMP FOR SHEET SO IT'LL NEVER DUPLICATE

      Worksheets.Add.Name = HiddenSheetName  ' CREATE NEW SHEET AND SET NAME TO TIMESTAMP REFERENCED ABOVE

      Sheets(HiddenSheetName).Select   'SELECT IT

      Range("A1").Select                  'SELECT A CELL

      Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"   ' APPLY CURRENT TOOLBAR 'FILL' COLOUR TO CELL

      Debug.Print Range("A1").Interior.Color  ' :: PRINT THIS VALUE TO LOG/IMMEDIATE WINDOW ::

      Application.DisplayAlerts = False  ' :: STOP ERROR WHEN DELETING SHEET

      Sheets(HiddenSheetName).Delete ' :: DELETE SHEET

      Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' :: ALLOW ERROR WHEN DELETING SHEET

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' :: UPDATE SCREEN AGAIN!

      End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't

Anyway, you can use a custom palette using this code:

> The modColorFunctions module contains a function named
>   ChooseColorDialog that will display a Windows Color Picker dialog and
>   return the RGB Long color value. If the user cancels the dialog, the
>   result is -1. For example,

```
Dim RGBColor As Long
Dim Default As Long
Default = RGB(255, 0, 255) 'default to purple
RGBColor = ChooseColorDialog(DefaultColor:=Default)
If RGBColor < 0 Then
    Debug.Print "*** USER CANCELLED"
Else
    Debug.Print "Choice: " & Hex(RGBColor)
End If
```

Taken from the chapter **Displaying A Color Picker Dialog** of http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Colors.aspx

You need to add the [color module](http://www.cpearson.com/Zips/modColorFunctions.zip) to make it work