# Excel shortcut for applying last used color with keyboard?

Tags: vba, colors, excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to color cells in Excel 2010 efficiently by only using the keyboard. However, the Excel shortcut for coloring a cell, Alt + H + H, is not that fast since you have to select the specific color with the arrows on your keyboard - which often is slower than using the mouse.

Quite often, the color you want to select is simply the last used color. When using the mouse, you can quickly color the cell with the last used color, since it's showing on the ribbon as the default color.

However, when using only the keyboard, I haven't found a way to quickly apply the last used color.

I tried to record a macro to do this, but the auto-generated code then referred to the *specific* last color used, not the last used color *in general*.

Does anyone know of a smart macro and/or shortcut that can solve this problem?

Thanks, 
Tarjei

Comment: I believe you are looking for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22847937/265487

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in a standard module:

```
Dim svColor

Sub Saveit()
    svColor = ActiveCell.Interior.Color
End Sub

Sub PasteIt()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Interior.Color = svColor
    Next r
End Sub
```

Then assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to **SaveIt()** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to **PasteIt()**
Click on a cell and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> to save its color and then click on other cells and touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to apply that color to them

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the F4 Key. It repeats the last command or action.

Select one cell and color it with your desired color (with the toolbar button).
Then go around with the cursor-keys and press F4 on the desired cells.