# Get the current Fill Color

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the current Fill Color in the ribbon using VBA? I like to manually select the Fill color to highlight entire rows with. I know I can highlight an entire row with code like `foo.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`. However, instead of setting it to `3`, I want to set it to the user's currently selected Fill Color in the ribbon.

I found a similar thread for Microsoft Word that uses `Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex`, but I have not found one for Microsoft Excel.

Edit: Sorry for the duplicate question. I am hoping there’s a better answer that doesn’t require an active selection first. If not I’ll accept Jonathan’s answer. Currently I am just highlighting the current cell with `CellFillColorPicker`, getting that cell’s color and then highlighting the row with that color.

Comment: I only know of a way where you need to select the range first and then execute: 
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question appears to be similar to this one: [VBA - use color already select in Excel to fill cell interior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083644/vba-use-color-already-select-in-excel-to-fill-cell-interior)

It looks like this is the code that you want:

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "CellFillColorPicker"

Comment: Well you need to select the range first. It doesn't return the current fill color, but it uses the current fill color on the selection.